Is it realistic to submit a grant proposal in which the only budget item is one person’s salary?
We are preparing an NSF grant application for which the only budget item is the salary of a senior software developer.
The team consists of:

The PI, a professor (whose time involvement will be very small)
a senior software developer who will do 95+% of the work. This person is on "soft money", i.e. their position depends on grant funding.

There are no other significant expenses associated with the project: maybe a few small resources totaling a few thousand dollars. It's an established project that is heavily used by academics and we know exactly what we need to do.
My question is whether this proposed budget will be seen as greedy or too simplistic, reducing the chance that our proposal will succeed.

Does your university claim a percentage of each grant to cover the costs of managing them?  Many (most?)do.

You ask "is it weird?", which is entirely subjective and not very meaningful.  Do you mean to ask "will this hurt my chances of getting funded?"  Or something else?  I suggest you edit it to ask what you really want to know.

@Buffy yes you are right, I didn't mention the 10% indirect costs. (We are applying through a nonprofit and using the de minimis rate for organizations without a federally negotiated rate.)

@DanielHatton Health insurance and retirement benefits are fringe costs, which are part of the budget. The 10% is indirect cost, which is on top of everything else and does, as you say, pay for buildings, electricity, internet, etc. You are right that 10% is not going to cover these costs, but if a nonprofit wants to charge only 10% for these costs, that is their prerogative.

NSF has multiple directorates and each have their own conventions. My experience as a funded PI and reviewer for the NSF is with my two "home" directorates in engineering and mathematical and physical sciences.
Within the context of my experience, what you describe would be a red flag, and I would certainly rank you quite low on a panel review. The reasons are that one of the main focal points of NSF funding is that it is intertwined with education and training. Typically, and through my conversations with program managers over the years, there is a strong preference towards funding graduate students, even over postdocs.
What is your educational/training component? Why should you even be funded if you are paying another expert to do most of the work outside of the traditional context of training in academia? This would certainly rank far lower at panel compared to another proposal that had all the traditional hallmarks of student training, outreach, education, etc...
There are other agencies where the budget, and such a request would be more fitting. Of course I could be completely wrong. So best to follow up with your program manager anyway.

I would phrase your need not directly as some academic project but rather as a need for equipment. The software engineer is not doing research and there is no education aspect as explained in the answer by R1NaNo. Rather you need a certain gadget as a means to perform your actual research. Once you have it you may also be able to use it to train students. Your gadget just happens to be non-physical because it is a piece of software. Lab scientists frequently have need of expensive pieces of machinery, so there are funding sources for that so I would recommend to look at it from that direction and then see what funding sources are available to you.

In many cases now days a software component is integral to the use/operation of any device or system - even to the extent of reprogramming it for various special modified uses , is this the case in this instance?

This is not a bad answer in principle, but granting agencies that have programs for infrastructure would usually not be willing to fund salaries rather than the purchase of physical equipment (maybe a piece of software to be bought from a vendor rather than developed in-house, although I would bet that even that wouldn't fall under their guidelines)

@BenBolker Disagree. NSF Major Research Instrumentation Program "An MRI award supports the acquisition of a multi-user research instrument that is commercially available... or for the personnel costs and equipment that are required for the development of an instrument with new capabilities, thereby advancing instrumentation capabilities and enhancing expertise for instrument design and fabrication at academic institutions." In fields like astrophysics and HEP, instrument design is a subfield unto itself.

OK, that's good. Do you know if it would also apply to software development? (i.e. could software be counted as an "instrument"?)

I don't know much about NSF, but I would probably raise issues under the discussion of budgetary concerns if I were on an NIH study section and saw this budget.
My concerns would be that the only major employee on the grant isn't a university employee, making this sound more like a subcontract to me.  If the developer is independent, I'd really argue that this should be considered a subcontract.
Think of it this way -- 95% of the grant budget is leaving the university!!  How is it possible to manage a grant under that circumstance.  Why would the grant need to go to the university?

Where does it say the developer isn't a university employee?

It is not right (won't say it "weird") that you didn't budget for overhead. If the grant goes to any university, they have a specific percentage (say 50%) for overhead.
Go to a grant officer at the university and ask for directions! Also, that person can help you with the format, depending on funding agency the format of the application may vary.
If you spend for example $150k in direct cost, any funding agency understands that an additional $70k will be going to overhead.
Also, once you move in the project, you will determine that you need a server / cloud computing / design services / testing etc. These are direct costs too. Try an anticipatory exercise and make a more detailed budget.
